# Adding a line break after PS1

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal

I'm trying to add a line break after my prompt.  Basically I want:

```
$ ls
                    <-- how do I get this line break?
file1 file2 file3
                    <-- this one is easy, PS1="\n$ " or whatnot
$
```

instead of

```
$ ls
file1 file2 file3
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Bash, you can use a script like [this one](http://www.twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/preexec.bash.txt) to provide `preexec` functionality.

Using `preexec`, you can add the newline after the prompt by editing your `.bash_profile` to include

```
preexec() { echo; }
preexec_install
```

Note that I had to modify line 125 of the above-linked script to read

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND} preexec_invoke_cmd"
```

on my OS X box.

Comment: @cwolves Or zsh has preexec support builtin.

Comment: `tcsh` has it too, as `postcmd`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want this functionality on a case by case basis, you could do this:

```
$ echo -e "\n" && ls
```

(i.e. tell echo to insert a newline, then run your regular command. The -e flag tells echo to interpret escape sequences. Not all system configurations need it)

For brevity you can create an alias, and use it whenever you want some whitespace

```
$ alias ws='echo -e "\n"'
$ ws && echo "I am padded text"

  I am padded text
```

Comment: You can even create an alias for `'echo -en "\n" && '` and then just call something like `pad echo "I am padded"`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to modify my general prompt somehow.